# Error getting kafka consumer lag with kafka-consumer-groups.sh

Tags: apache-kafka

I’m having an issue with using the Kafka command line tools to get consumer lag for a given group/topic. Currently, I'm trying to use `kafka-consumer-groups.sh` as mentioned in countless online resources. The following command works just fine: `kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server $BROKERS --list`

However, if I use `kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server $BROKERS --describe --group $GROUP`, I get the following output and error:

```
Note: This will only show information about consumers that use the Java consumer API (non-ZooKeeper-based consumers).

[2018-07-24 00:19:09,139] ERROR admin-client-network-thread exited (kafka.admin.AdminClient) java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.join(Utils.java:399)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.requests.OffsetFetchRequest$Builder.toString(OffsetFetchRequest.java:74)
        at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientRequest.toString(ClientRequest.java:63)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.doSend(NetworkClient.java:374)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.send(NetworkClient.java:332)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.trySend(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:409)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:252)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:208)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:199)
        at kafka.admin.AdminClient$$anon$1.run(AdminClient.scala:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Error: Executing consumer group command failed due to The server experienced an unexpected error when processing the request
```

I've tried setting `GROUP` to each and every group available and I've used KafkaTool to confirm that these groups exist and are working properly (consuming messages from various topics). I've tried placing strings in the command directly instead of using an environment variable.

Why am I getting this error and what else can I do to debug?

Comment: What version of Kafka is this for?

Comment: @vahid - It seems like a version older than 0.11.0.0 as this error is from a deprecated client  https://github.com/axbaretto/kafka/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/kafka/admin/AdminClient.scala. But the interesting is that the method where this error gets caught just has a simple loop with a poll() method call for a ConsumerNetworkClient object. The poll(Long) method is chained - https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/internals/ConsumerNetworkClient.java. Perhaps, something is going wrong in the last method in that chain ??

Comment: I see '--new-consumer' missing:
./kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server x.x.x.x:9092 --new-consumer  --group testGroup --describe